# How to wrap a C-function with python-cffi so that pythons keyword-arguments work?

Tags: python, c, wrapper, keyword-argument, python-cffi

Using the [API mode, calling C sources instead of a compiled library](https://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html#api-mode-calling-c-sources-instead-of-a-compiled-library) in the python-cffi framework I want to call my c-function in python with keyword arguments. Is there an inbuilt feature in cffi for this? Otherwise I would have to write a python wrapper around my cffi-wrapped c-functions which I don't want to do since it seems like an ugly solution.

(*run both files with python, should work out-of-the-box if cffi and gcc are present: "python example_extension_build.py && python test_example.py"*)

Note: That in this Example code I use the [API level, out-of-line](https://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html#purely-for-performance-api-level-out-of-line) mode instead (for clearnes)

```
# file: example_extension_build.py
from cffi import FFI
ffibuilder = FFI()

# objects shared between c and python
ffibuilder.cdef("""
    struct my_s{ int a; char * b; };
    int my_f(int, struct my_s);
""")

# definitions of the python-c shared objects
ffibuilder.set_source("_example",r"""

    struct my_s{ int a; char * b; };

    #include <stdio.h>
    int my_f(int arg_1, struct my_s arg_2) // some random example function
    {
        printf("%s\n", arg_2.b); 
        return arg_1 + arg_2.a;
    }

""", sources=[])

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    ffibuilder.compile(verbose=True)
```

And the python calls

```
# file: test_example.py
import _example as e

n = 21;

s = e.ffi.new("struct my_s *")
s.a = 21
s.b = e.ffi.new("char[]", b"Hello World!")

# e.lib.my_f(arg_2=s[0], arg_1=n); # <-- Here is what I want
e.lib.my_f(n, s[0]); # the standard way
```

Answer (score 0):

As of today – May 18 2021 – it is not possible to wrap a c function with cffi as to expose keyword arguments to python. This answer was provided by Armin Rigo on the cffi mailing list [here](https://groups.google.com/g/python-cffi/c/I3uqcfjURsI/m/FphmlYjtAQAJ) (a patch to provide this feature will be accepted by [Armin Rigo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1556290/armin-rigo), if certain conditions are fulfilled). The only possible solution then is to wrap the cffi-wrapped c-function in python code (ugh).

Note: Even uglier will it get, if one wanted to set a default argument value for arg_2

```py
# file: test_wrap.py
import _example as e

def my_f(arg_1, arg_2) :
    return e.lib.my_f(arg_1, arg_2)

n = 21

s = e.ffi.new("struct my_s *")
s.a = 21
s.b = e.ffi.new("char[]", b"Hello World!")

sol = my_f(arg_2=s[0], arg_1=n) # <-- Here is what I want

print(sol)
```

On the command line

```
$ python test_wrap.py
Hello World!
42
```